# Is a for/break more efficient than iterator().next()?

Tags: java, foreach, break

It is known that mapX has a single entry in it.  A code metric tool complains about using 'break' inside for loops, but normally, in such a small loop, I'd let it pass.  In this case though, with it known that there's only a single entry, I'm not sure which is more efficient.

So, which of the following is more efficient when you know that the map will only ever contain one element?

Possible replacement:

```
Map.Entry<String,String> e = mapX.entrySet().iterator().next();
Y.setMsg(e.getValue());
Y.setMsgKey(e.getKey());
```

Original code:

```
for (String key : mapX.keySet()){
    Y.setMsg(mapX.get(key));
    Y.setMsgKey(key);
    break;
}
```

Comment: How about not using either?

Comment: Why do you have a map at all, if there's only ever going to be one entry?

Comment: @azurefrog You took the words out of my mouth.

Comment: Does the replacement still work if the set is empty?

Comment: Why do you have a break in the for loop if you know it's only going to run once anyway? To avoid the high cost of an extra `hasNext()` call? Generating the `keySet()` is probably more expensive.

Comment: i'd use the first version purely for clarity.  it's obvious the intent of the code.  if i stumbled upon the second version in code, i'd have to stare at it for a while to figure out what the heck it's doing.

Comment: The map is a container for validation messages.  The code that fills it is designed to handle multiple validation criteria, but in this case there's only one criterion.  The code to fetch the message is only run if there is a message to process, so there's no chance of an empty map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first version is faster than the second one (with the "for" loop / "break"):

1. The loop version has to call `hasNext()` before the call to `next()`.
2. The loop version is iterating the keySet rather than the entryset, and therefore has to do an extra map lookup to get the corresponding value.
3. The loop version possibly has an extra branch instruction at the `break` ... though this is minor and can possibly be optimized away by the JIT compiler.

But the **best reason** for using the first version (IMO) is that the code is easier to understand / less complex.  (The code metric tool is helpful in this case ...)

---

Of course, the flip-side is that if the map is empty, the non-looping version of the code is going to throw an exception.  If you need to deal with the "empty map" case, you should write it like this:

```
if (!mapX.isEmpty()) {
    Map.Entry<String,String> e = mapX.entrySet().iterator().next();
    y.setMsg(e.getValue());
    y.setMsgKey(e.getKey());
}
```

Comment: also, the loop version has an extra map lookup.  if it used the entrySet(), your description would be accurate.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that ... fixed

Comment: I prefered the iterator().next() version myself, but wasn't sure if there might have been another reason to go with the for loop.  Thanks!

Comment: @EdwinW `Iterables.get(iterable, 0)` is preferable over `iterable.iterator().next()` if you only need the first element as it prevents the need for creating a `new Iterator<?>`. It's unfortunate that `Iterables` comes from a library, java doesn't provide it from standard libraries.

Comment: @Unihedron Unfortunately, in this project, unless there's a lot of these one-message issues, adding another library is not going to be accepted.

Comment: @Unihedron - *"...as it prevents the need for creating a new Iterator<?>"* .  It is more complicated than that.  That optimization only happens for `Iterable` objects that can be cast to `List`.  In other words, not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find first variant more concise. If you're using [`guava`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), you could also write it like this:

```
Map.Entry<String,String> e = Iterables.getOnlyElement(mapX.entrySet());
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
Map.Entry<String,String> e = mapX.entrySet().iterator().next();
Y.setMsg(e.getValue());
Y.setMsgKey(e.getKey());
```

is the same as

```
for (String key : mapX.keySet()){
    Y.setMsg(mapX.get(key));
    Y.setMsgKey(key);
    break;
}
```

with one exception: The loop first calls `hasNext()` on the iterator.

The former implies more strongly that there's only one element (at least, only one that you're interested in). The latter says "I'm going to loop through all elements...except I'm going to stop after the first one." Why use a loop, if you're not going to loop?

Seems like the non-looping version is the one to go with.